# Matrix Dimensionality

Tags: matrices

So in my class today we discussed GMM estimation and how we can derive OLS using GMM. I am struggling with the matrix algebra with GMM (from Summations to Matricies)

$$g(x,\theta)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n g(x_i,\theta)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \textbf{x}_i'(y_i-\textbf{x}_i'\beta)=\frac{1}{n}\textbf{X}'(\textbf{y}-\textbf{X}\beta)$$

How did we get this for example...

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\textbf{x}_i'y_i=\frac{1}{n}\textbf{X}'\textbf{y}$$

and this for example

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\textbf{x}_i'\textbf{x}_i\beta=\frac{1}{n}\textbf{X}'\beta$$

from the summation into Matrix from

Because I thought

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\textbf{x}_i\textbf{x}_i'=\textbf{X}'\textbf{X}$$

Comment: The title gives little clue as to what GMM and OLS mean.  A bit of explanation or better title would help us read the Question with understanding.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i'y_i=\begin{bmatrix}x_1' & \ldots&x_n' \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\ \vdots \\ y_n\end{bmatrix}=X'y$$

Your second last equation is wrong.

It should be

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i'x_i \beta=\frac{1}{n}X'X\beta$$

which comes from your last equation.